# Explicit diagonalisation transformation for this complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I need to diagonalise a complex $2\times2$ matrix, $M$. I need the explicit diagonalisation transformation, i.e. a matrix, $S$ s.t. $S^{-1}MS= \text{diag}(m_1,m_2)$. I am talking about a matrix of the form:

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} a^2 & ic \\ ic & b^2 \end{pmatrix} $$
where $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers. We want to restrict ourselves to the assumption $(a^2-b^2)^2>4c^2$.

As one usually does, I caclulated the eigenvalues $m_{1/2}$,
$$m_{1/2} =\frac{1}{2} \left( a^2+b^2 \pm \sqrt{(a^2-b^2)^2-4c^2} \right)$$
Our assumption means that these are real. Two linearly independent eigenvectors (one for each eigenvalue) are

$$\mathbf{x}_{1/2}=  \begin{pmatrix} ic \\ m_{1/2}-a^2 \end{pmatrix} $$
It is quickly shown that the two are actually eigenvectors. Now I continued from there by normalising the eigenvectors, using the norm in $\mathbb{C}^2$,i.e. $\|\mathbf{x}_{1/2}\|^2 = c^2+(m_{1/2}-a^2)^2$. Having normalised my eigenvectors I wrote them in the rows of a matrix. Denoting $A_{1/2} = \|\mathbf{x}_{1/2}\|$ this gives
$$\mathbf{S} =  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{ic}{A_1} & \frac{m_1-a^2}{A_1}\\  \frac{ic}{A_2} & \frac{m_2-a^2}{A_2} \end{pmatrix}
$$
However, when I calculated $S^{-1}MS$, the result was not diagonal (although there may of course be mistakes). I have no experience with diagonalising complex matrices and I know that it is not always possible do diagonalise a complex matrix. I really need to know if I just made a mistake in my calculation or if something more serious went wrong in my derivation of $S$.

**Edit**: Just found this related question [Finding Eigensystem of Hermitian Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609482/finding-eigensystem-of-hermitian-matrix?rq=1). However that is just a special case, does it work in the general case with $a,b,c>0$ as well?

Comment: If the eigenvalues are distinct, the matrix is diagonalizable. That is not the issue here. You have made a mistake somewhere. Did you determine $S^{-1}$ correctly?

Comment: 1. There is no need to "normalize" the eigenvectors, although there is no harm in doing it either. 2. I think you are confusing $S$ and its transpose. The eigenvectors should be the columns (you have them as the rows) of $S$ for there to hold $MS = SD$.

Comment: @Dan Fox: I have made exactly this mistake, thank you for pointing that out. Now at least my matrix $S$ diagonalises $M$ via $S^{-1}MS$. However, the resulting matrix is not orthogonal. I have found transformation $S'$ that diagonalises M AND such that $S'$ happens to be orthogonal, meaning $(S')^{-1}= (S')^T$. Is it surprising that there are both orthogonal AND non-orthogonal diagonalisation transformations?

Comment: @user154037: In general there are many matrices $S$ that diagonalize a given diagonalizable matrix $M$. For example, suppose $M = SDS^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal. If $E$ is diagonal, then $EDE^{-1} = D$ so $T = SE$ satisfies $M = TDT^{-1}$. That $S$ be orthogonal is equivalent to its columns being orthonormal. In general if the eigenvalues of $M$ are distinct, the columns of $S$ will be orthogonal, but not orthonormal until rescaled; such a rescaling amounts to replacing $S$ by $SE$ where the elements of $E$ are the reciprocals of the norms of the columns of $S$.